# Equivalent impedance of a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel, series, equivalent-circuit

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent impedance of the right side of this circuit (so the capacity, inductance and right resistance) :

[image]

I see this result in the solution of my exercice:

[image]

But I don't see how L et R are in parallel, are they not in series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of view for the impedance is not clear.
The solution that shown is for the part of the circuit as shown in my diagram.

$$Z_{\text(ab)}=Z_C//(Z_L+Z_R)$$
You should be able to find the solution from here.

And yes, the inductor and the resistor are in series. And the solution is correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmZtlX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the Zl and R are in series and their sum is in parallel with Zc if you look at them from the nodes of the capacitor. And thus, the equation should be correct.

If you are confused, re-drawing the circuit helps in such a way that it preserves its topology:

If you measure at node a-b:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkVw0h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is the same as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2rmIM.png)</sup>

Effective Impedance Zab:
$$
Z_{ab} = Z_C \parallel (Z_L + R) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_C} + \frac{1}{Z_L + R}}
$$

---

But if you measure at another node, e.g. Zo, the impedance will be entirely different:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv3NoB.png)</sup>

Effective Impedance Zo:
$$
Z_{o} = (Z_C + Z_L) \parallel R = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_C + Z_L} + \frac{1}{R}}
$$